# Flutter FilterChip's tab effect being casted by chip background color

Tags: dart, flutter

When I tapped one of those chips, I found that rectangular shadows

animated under the chips, especially when I assigned specific

background colors of chips.

With no background color, shadows(or can I say it tap effect?) are above

chips like normal RaisedButtons.

I just want to remove this shadows.

```
Wrap(
  spacing: 10.0,
  children: List<Widget>.generate(aList.length, (int index) {
    return FilterChip(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
      // avatar: CircleAvatar(
      //   child: Icon(Icons.add),
      // ),
      selectedColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
      label: Text(
        bList[index],
      ),
      labelStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
      selected: _selectState == aList[index],
      onSelected: (bool selected) {
        if (!selected) {
          _formData['shop'] = '';
          setState(() {
            _selectState = '';
          });
        } else if (selected) {
          _formData['shop'] = aList[index];
          setState(() {
            _selectState = aList[index];
          });
        }
      },
    );
  }).toList(),
)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwwCd.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9Qqs.jpg)

Comment: Do you want 4th Widget to look like others?

Comment: just want to remove that effet. And in those pictures, not underlined chips are not tapped yet. only tapped chips make that shadow animation like tapping raisedbuttons.